# function overloading in swift

Tags: swift, overloading

I am trying to create two methods with the following arguments but the compiler is complaining that they are ambiguous. I am following a youtube series to learn Swift and it seems to be fine in the video there. What am I missing?

`func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double){`

`func performOperation(operation:(Double, Double)->Double){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may be running into the same problem mentioned in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/34yusl/help_with_function_overloading/). It looks like the solution may just be to rename your functions, due to a clash with inherited with Objective C methods.

e.g.

```
func myPerformOperation(operation: Double -> Double){

func myPerformOperation(operation:(Double, Double)->Double){
```

(These aren't ideal names—they should be more descriptive—but you get the idea.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, renaming didn't work, but making them `private` did

Comment: @AD.Net Was there an Objective-C context for this question similar to the reddit thread Cory linked?