# How to fix overload issue?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, core-animation, overloading

Am trying to fix few bugs in  UX when implementing the pod from folding cell from RAMotion [github link for pod](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell)

However looked into few resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690076/multiple-functions-with-the-same-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687503/function-overloading-in-swift) was unable to understand the issue.

in FileA in the given function shows an error saying:

> Argument labels '`(rawValue:)`' do not match any available overloads

```
fileprivate func convertToCAMediaTimingFunctionName(_ input: String) -> CAMediaTimingFunctionName {
    return CAMediaTimingFunctionName(rawValue: input as String)
}
```

while looking in the `CAMediaTimingFunctionName` it has following code

```
/* CoreAnimation - CAMediaTimingFunction.h

   Copyright (c) 2006-2018, Apple Inc.
   All rights reserved. */

public struct CAMediaTimingFunctionName : Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {

    public init(rawValue: String)
}
```

[image: the actual error location]
Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: I copied that function into a Swift Playground and it compiled just fine. Which version of iOS and which version of Swift are you using?

Comment: I saw the build version as 4.0 so i changed it as 4.2 closed and build it back again it shows the same error !!

Comment: The code you posted works just fine for me. If you can't post code that actually reproduces the error, it is going to be difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: i have added a screen shot of the error

Comment: You can use it like this ```CAMediaTimingFunctionName(string: "something")```. Make sure UIKit is imported in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some issues with the said RAmotion project as it was orginally designed for swift 3 later few updates were made.

However, with the limited information would suggest in saying to try something like this

```
fileprivate func convertToCAMediaTimingFunctionName(_ input: String) -> CAMediaTimingFunctionName {
    return CAMediaTimingFunctionName(string:input )
```